# HKMO-2020 Math contest

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math

Question from math contest (already concluded in 2020) which I have tried but not yet found any elegant solution.

How many positive integer solutions does the following system of equations have?

$$\sqrt{2020}(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} )= \sqrt{ (c+ 2020)(d+ 2020)}$$

$$\sqrt{2020}(\sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c} )= \sqrt{ (d+ 2020)(a+ 2020})$$

$$\sqrt{2020}(\sqrt{c} + \sqrt{d} )= \sqrt{ (a+ 2020)(b+ 2020)}$$

$$\sqrt{2020}(\sqrt{d} + \sqrt{a} )= \sqrt{ (b+ 2020)(c+ 2020)}$$
My attempt:

After few manipulations with an aim to remove the radicals, I end up with:

$$4040 \left(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{cd}+\sqrt{da}\right)=ab+bc+cd+da+4\cdot 2020^2$$

Before I go further, I feel that it is only going to become more unwieldy. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Applying the [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#%E2%84%9D2_-_The_plane) to $(u_1,v_1,u_2,v_2) = (\sqrt{c},\sqrt{2020},\sqrt{2020},\sqrt{d})$ to the right hand side of the first equation

$$\sqrt{(c+2020)(2020+d)} \ge \sqrt{c}\sqrt{2020}+\sqrt{2020}\sqrt{d}= \sqrt{2020}(\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{d})$$
Then
$$\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\ge \sqrt{c}+\sqrt{d} \tag{1}$$

Do the same method for the next 3 equation, we deduce
$$\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\ge \sqrt{d}+\sqrt{a} \tag{2}$$
$$\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{d}\ge \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\tag{3}$$
$$\sqrt{d}+\sqrt{a}\ge \sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\tag{4}$$

From $(1)(3)$ we deduce $$\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}= \sqrt{c}+\sqrt{d}$$
and the equality occurs when
$$\frac{c}{2020} = \frac{2020}{d}$$
$$\frac{a}{2020} = \frac{2020}{b}$$

Do the same thing, from $(2)(4)$, we must have
$$\frac{b}{2020} = \frac{2020}{c}$$
$$\frac{d}{2020} = \frac{2020}{a}$$

Hence, we have

$$\frac{a}{2020}=\frac{2020}{b}=\frac{c}{2020}=\frac{2020}{d} $$

or
$$(a,b,c,d)=\left(t,\frac{2020^2}{t},t,\frac{2020^2}{t}  \right) \tag{5}$$

From $(5)$, we have $t| 2020^2 = (2^4 5^2 101^2)$ So, there are $(4+1)(2+1)(2+1)=45$ different values of $t$.

**Conclusion**: there are $45$ solutions

$$(a,b,c,d)=\left(t,\frac{2020^2}{t},t,\frac{2020^2}{t}  \right) \qquad \forall t| 2020^2$$

Comment: How many of those solutions are integer solutions, though?

Comment: @CSquared Yes, I though $(a,b,c,d)\in \Bbb R^+$. I modify the answer to get the positive integer numbers.

Comment: As per the Answer Key, there are 45 integer solutions

Comment: Nice analytical solution. Correcting the ending: the actual condition on $t > 0$ is that $2020t,2020/t$ are integers. So $t$ is a rational number such that $v_p(t) =0$ if $p \neq 2,5,101$ and $|v_2(t)| \leq 2$, $|v_5(t)| \leq 1$, $|v_{101}(t)| \leq 1$. That makes $5 \cdot 3 \cdot 3=45$ solutions.

Comment: @Mathronza There are 45 solutions. I modified the ending.  Mindlack: thank you